Pushing data from Azure Storage Account to Azure DevOps Repo Daily
I've created python script that pulls data structures from SQL DB (Tables, views, indexes, SPs) and saves them on Azure Storage Account in folder with 'DD-MM-YYYY' format.
I want to create a next module that takes these scripts from the folder and pushes them to the Azure DevOps Repo as a commit the new branch that is instantly merged to the main, so I can see daily changes done on the database.
Is it possible to do it on Databricks or I have to use DevOps pipelines? If DevOps is only way, how can I do this?

What things do you want to push to Azure Repos from Azure Storage Account? The python scripts, or the whole folder "DD-MM-YYYY" of daily data fetched from SQL DB?

Whole folder in which are scripts that are stored quite similary as SQL DB Project that you can pull from Visual Studio.

So, what you want is the python script pulls data structures from SQL DB to Azure Storage Account, and save the data in folder "DD-MM-YYYY" daily, and then you also want to pull the whole folder "DD-MM-YYYY" from Azure Storage Account to Azure Repos daily. Right?  @KacperG

@BrightRan-MSFT - right, the first part is done as it scripts daily DB to a storage. I'm looking for a solution for the next step.

In pipeline, you can use the Azure CLI "az storage copy" to copy folders from Azure storage account to local directory of the agent machine, and then use git command to commit and push the folders to Azure Repos.

Ensure the latest daily data with folder (e.g., 06-08-2024) has existed in the storage account. In my below example, the folders are stored in a container (daily-sqldb-data) of the storage account.


In Azure DevOps, I have a git repository (daily-sqldb-data). Go to "Project Settings" > "Repositories", on the "Security" tab of the repository, ensure the following two identities have permission "Contribute" set to "Allow".

Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})
{Project Name} Build Service ({Organization Name})



In Azure DevOps, go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create an Azure Resource Manager service connection (ARM connection) that can connect and access to the Azure Subscription where the storage account is in.

In pipeline, you can use the AzureCLI@2 task to run the command "az storage copy".


# azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  accountName: 'storagebriran'
  containerName: 'daily-sqldb-data'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

# Create a temporary local branch named as the format 'DD-MM-YYYY' to receive the data downloaded from storage account.
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Create temporary branch'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      git config --global user.name "[Auto-Boot]"
      git config --global user.email AutoBoot@example.com

      branchName=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=folderName;]$branchName"

      echo "Create '$branchName' branch."
      git branch $branchName
      git checkout $branchName

# Download data folder 'DD-MM-YYYY' from storage account.
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Download Daily Data'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'myArmConnection'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo "Download entire folder '$(folderName)' from container '$(containerName)' of Storage account '$(accountName)'."
      az storage copy -s https://$(accountName).blob.core.windows.net/$(containerName)/$(folderName) -d "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" --recursive

# Merge the download data folder 'DD-MM-YYYY' from the local temporary branch to the local main branch.
# Commit and push the updates form the local main branch to remote.
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Merge and Push Daily Data'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      git add --all
      git commit -m "Add daily data in '$(folderName)' folder."

      echo "----------------------------------------------"
      echo "Merge daily data to main branch."
      git checkout main
      git merge $(folderName)
      git branch -d $(folderName)

      echo "----------------------------------------------"
      echo "Pushing changes to remote..."
      git add --all
      git commit -m "Merge daily data from '$(folderName)' branch."
      git push


If you want the pipeline can be automatically triggered daily, you can set Scheduled triggers to it.
# Disbale CI trigger.
trigger: none

# Trigger the pipeline at 23:00 UTC everyday. The time zone for cron schedules is UTC.
# If you want to schedule a time in your time zone, you need to calculate the corresponding UTC time.
# For example, the time 22:00 in UTC+8 time zone is 14:00 in UTC time zone.
schedules:
- cron: 0 23 * * *
  displayName: 'Daily run at 23:00 UTC'
  branches:
    include:
    - main

. . .

steps:
. . .



I got following error:
failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list files due to reason HEAD https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/tech/tech_SQL_Repo/2024-08-05
RESPONSE 403: 403 Key based authentication is not permitted on this storage account.
ERROR CODE: KeyBasedAuthenticationNotPermitted
is there need to make extra authorization?

@KacperG, As I mentioned above, when you set up the ARM connection, ensure the Service Principal used by the connection has the access to the storage account. you can try to manually run "az login" with the same Service Principal from your local machine, then manually  run the same "az storage copy" command to see if it cam work. If also not work, check the permission of the Service Principal on the storage account.
